# an application wants to access the keyring default but it is locked then black screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, gpu-driver, gnome-keyring

I'm having this problem, after I start the computer, ubuntu 20.04 is booted, I reach the moment were I get the form to input the password for "an application wants to access the keyring default but it is locked", and after a couple seconds the image turns black.

I have to add that this is very probably originated in a video card driver problem.

This is my original problem, after trying to solve this by differnt ways, this problem changed. After the image turns black, a very quick list of lines, like the ones that happen during the booting appears on the screen and disappears, after this the screen goes black, and every 4-5 seconds appears a white "_" on the top left of the screen, and this never stops

Hardware Specifications:

- CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
- GPU: GeForece 560 ti
- 32GB RAM
- Motherboard: B550-A PRO

I appreciate any help,

Thanks

Comment: First things first, if you enabled autologin then disable it. Also please [edit] your question and post hardware specifications.

Comment: I disabled the autologin, now it goes directly to the black screen, the first times the cursor appears and desappears every 4-5 seconds, but after starts titilating and doesn't stop

Comment: Assuming you correctly installed the Nvidia drivers (likely during the OS installation by selecting the option to install 3rd party drivers, etc.) then **disable Secure Boot in UEFI** and try again.

Comment: The Secure Boot is disabled, the driver part should be the problem. The driver was working correctly, until the last update, after that the driver wasn't working and by trying to find one that works, I ended up with this problem

Comment: That makes sense indeed. Keep in mind Ubuntu almost always install the recommended version and users don't need to *and shouldn't* mess with it directly. When they do is when $hit happens. 650ti is based on the legacy Kepler chipset architecture and *isn't* supported by newer versions, it should run in Ubuntu with 390 or 470 branches only. What exactly did you tried to do with Nvidia drivers prior to noticing the problem?

Comment: Exactly, I found some .run for 390, I think, there were some versions available depending on my kernel version, but the installation was failing. So I tried with different ones, until one didn't fail, and after the reboot I ended up with this problem.

Comment: I've tried removing everything from nvidia with apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*, but I'm not sure it deleted everything, or that it takes me to the origianl state, where no driver was set. I also have to say, that I execute this comands in the root console from the recovery mode of Grub

Comment: I also made a mistake posting my GPU, it's not 650 ti, but 560 ti, even older

Comment: ALL drivers are available in the Ubuntu repository. DON'T use Nvidia's binaries. If you did then uninstalling is NOT done with `apt`which is only for installing/uninstalling drivers from the repo. Any 500 series is still supported by the 390 branch and that version only (for how long, who knows?).

Comment: If you used the Nvidia binary (.run file) then to uninstall it you need to run the exact same command againdt the file but with the `--uninstall` parameter. Please check Nvidia's instructions for more details. Then just open Software & Updates > Additional drivers, select & apply the recommended version (should be only 390 suggested), reboot.

Comment: Ok, I manage to resolve this. I tried your advice, and I had only one of these files with permissions to execute, and the uninstall say it wasn't installed, I think there was a problem during the install so it didn't finish. And I think then the problem should have been, there are 3 options in "software & updates" about the drivers to install, the first is the recommended and I it wasn't working, so I guess one of the others got installed and it was the problem.

Comment: So what I did, was giving execute permissions to one of the downloaded drivers (the one that fitted better from the ones without permissions), and it worked. This also transformed the 3 options in 4 options, and the fourth one is "continue using a manually installed driver". Thank you for your help, without it would never have realized that the manually downloaded files weren't installed